# Why is My Jenkins not work with TestSuit of Katalon

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

My TestCase run in Katalon: **OK**.

My TestSuit run in Jenkins: **Not OK**.

I don't know why? I checked config and it is OK. 
I think the related issue is that Jenkins installation is wrong.

Comment: Added "katalon-studio" tag. Please, add some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download & Update Last **Jenkins.war** 
Bug is Pass